# FileNotFoundException on resource get from Tomcat

Tags: java, url, tomcat

I am running Tomcat 5.0 and I have problem with getting a resource from tomcats 'webapps' from Java. There is a html file that I check if it's available after server start in

```
  tomcat_folder/webapps/myProject/site.html
```

In Java I run this code when server is started:

```
  URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/myProject/site.html");
  URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
  Object content = con.getContent();
```

getContent() throws FileNotFoundException.

But when I put "http://localhost:8080/myProject/site.html" into browser, the site is displayed without problems.

Also I tested that on 4 machines - on 2 everything is fine, on other 2 FileNotFoundException.

I thought it might be some folder security access problem or user rights, but in the end I have no clue. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using the path on the file system i.e.
`URL url = new URL("C:/tomcat/webapps/myProject/site.html");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.

The cause was a windows service using port 8080, which was also in use by Tomcat. Resource was available through browser, but not from Java code.
After stopping conflicting service everything works as it should now.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are on windows. You may need to add java.exe to your virus scanner / firewall to allow it to make out bound network connections.

Comment: That was good idea. So I allowed full access for all java.exe processes I found and problem unfortunately still persists.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it may have helped but Im not sure virus scanners block localhost connections.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is in servlet then you can get the real path of your servlet and then append the file name to it.

```
String servletPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
URL url = new URL(servletPath+"site.html");
```

For normal java application you will need the entire path to the webapps folder of your tomcat installation.

Comment: Nope, it's in normal Java application outside server.

Comment: Ok, tried new URL("file:///C:/tomcat/webapps/myProject/site.html") and returned object is null (since giving no 'file:///' gives error of unknown protocol). Tried url for some file outside tomcat and I got also null reference, so I don't know if it's right way of using it or java can't access anything through URL like that.

Comment: Dont' use that `file:///` directly use this instead `URL("C:/tomcat/webapps/myProject/site.html") `

Comment: As I said in previous comment, direct `URL("C:/whatever")` throws a `java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c`.

Comment: Also I have tried `file:///someLocation` on the machine where the code from 1st post works and it's ok. What would that mean if on another machine pointing same thing throws FileNotFoundException?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct.
but you missed to actually connect

con .connect();

 before trying to getContent

Comment: The code without `con.connect()` works too - there's just some issue on another machine that I need to resolve.